# How to use Exception handling in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to write a program using `try catch` block but i couldn't write it,But i wrote in simple way but how to get it in catch try block..Here in my case i have displayed error message  that i want from try catch block please help me do that..any answer would be greatly appreciated..

```
   declare @a int
    declare @b int
    set @b=1
    set @a=3
    if (@a%2)<>0
    begin
      print 'You are entered odd number it is invalid number'
    end
    else
     while @b<=20
     begin
       print @a*@b 
       set @b=@b+1
    end
```

It should display the error message using `try catch` block please help me to write it..

Comment: This sounds a LOT like homework. Perhaps you can demonstrate what you have tried and we can help you finalize it.

Comment: there are plenty of examples of using try..catch on the internet. Find one and then show an example of how you've implemented it. Also, be clear in what you ask, are you trying to throw an error and then catch it ?

Comment: Is this really SQL2008 and not 2008R2?

Comment: Many source available in internet.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this:

```
    declare @a int
declare @b int
set @b=1
set @a=3
BEGIN TRY  
if (@a%2)<>0
begin
--For Example I add flowing line to rise error
set @a=@b/0
  print 'You are entered odd number it is invalid number'
end
else
 while @b<=20
 begin
   print @a*@b 
   set @b=@b+1
end
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
 PRINT Error_message()
 PRINT ERROR_NUMBER ( )  
END CATCH;
```

Comment: OP has tagged this as SQL2008 (i.e. NOT SQL2008R2) so this will *not* work.

Comment: I tested it in sqlserver 2014 ,sqlserver 2008R2 it was ok

Comment: @AmirhosseinYari `SQL Server 2008 R2` ≠ `SQL Server 2008`.  I'm not even going to make a comment on `SQL Server 2014`...

Answer (score -2):

Here you go

```
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @a INT
    DECLARE @b INT

    SET @b=1
    SET @a=3

    IF ( @a%2 ) <> 0
      BEGIN
          PRINT 'You are entered odd number it is invalid number'
      END
    ELSE WHILE @b <= 20
      BEGIN
          PRINT @a * @b

          SET @b=@b + 1
      END
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT Error_message()
END CATCH
```